# Baire's Category Theorem : Open subset of Complate metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, solution-verification, baire-category

Question: X is complete metric space and A is non-empty open subset of X then A has to be second category.

> I'm trying to prove this question and I did the following proof but I'm not so sure.  Do I have a mistake?  Can you check please?

Facts:We know X is a complete metric space and B is non-empty closed subset of X then B is a complete metric subspace of X and every complete metric space is second category. If A is first category there is exists $\{E_n\}\subset X$ closed subset collection such that $\forall n \in \Bbb{N}; Int(Cl(E_n))={\overline{E_n}}^o=\emptyset$ and $X=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$. Also I used A,B closed sets then $\overline{(A \cup B)}=\overline{A}\cup \overline{B}$ so  $\{A^n\}$ closed sets collection then $\overline{\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n}=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\overline{A_n}$

> Proof:Let assume there is a A open non-empty subset of X and A is first category. Then we can say there is exist $\{E_n\}\subset A$ closed collection such that $\forall n \in \Bbb{N}; Int(Cl(E_n))={\overline{E_n}}^o=\emptyset$ and $A=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$.If we take closure both sides we get  $$\overline{A}=\overline{\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n}=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\overline{E_n}=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$$ $\forall n \in \Bbb{N};E_n$ is closed then $\overline{E_n}=E_n$  $\overline{A}\supset A $ then we can easily say $\overline{A}$ is first category. But $\overline{A}$ closed subset of then has to be complete metric subspace then $\overline{A}$ is second category this is a contradicton. Then there is no A first category non-empty subset in X

Comment: You're basically done.  Instead, write $\overline{A} = \partial (A) \cup (\cup \overline{E_n})$.  Then the closures of the $E_n$ in $X$ (which you took relative to $A$, not $X$; be careful about that) are equal to their closures in $A$ plus whatever's in the boundary, so you'll get that $\overline{A}$ is first category, a contradiction.  Use that the boundary is closed, ofc.

Comment: Thank you  so much